# Why would StringUtils return the incorrect # of matches of a substring?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-stringutils

I am using StringUtils from the apache commons library to check the # of matches of a substring within the source code of an html page.

I have converted the page source using the webdriver command:

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

The code I am using to find # of matches is:

```
int cloudfCount = StringUtils.countMatches(pageSource, "cloudfront");
System.out.println("There are " + cloudfCount + " instances of cloudf text found within the page source.");
```

When I perform the check manually, I get 2 matches. Which is what I am expecting.

But when I use the above code in an automated Selenium script, I am getting 5 results.

Any thoughts/ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Add a log statement which will show what is the content of pageSource

Comment: My understanding is that the content of pageSource would be a string that contains all the page source code from the URL declared in driver.

Comment: Ok so I output the pageSource string to a text file, and when I did a search for "cloudfront" in notepad, there was only 1 result returned?!?!? What the??

Why am I getting 3 different results?

Answer (score 0):

@kevin it would be great if you could provide us with contents of pagesource.
Another thing, if the page has been modified it wont be necessary you get the current page source, pls refer [getPageSource Doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource())

If anyhow getPageSource ain't working and you need the text within body tag, you could use:
`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent` using JavascriptExecutor,

and then try out `StringUtils.countMatches()`.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the page is being modified by Javascript, since the substrings I am searching for are located within a JS URL...